# Opening table shows "Enter parameter value"

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I've done something to my Access database, and now when I double-click a table (all Access Objects | Tables) it puts up the "Enter Parameter Value" dialog. The parameter that it is asking for is of the form TableName.ColumnName, and ColumnName is indeed a column in TableName, but TableName is NOT the table I am opening. As it is a table I am opening, not a query or report etc., I have no idea what is causing this or what to do about it. If I just hot OK it seems to then open the table fine, but I'd like to fix it if I can.

Comment: When you open the table in Design View and then open its property sheet, do you see `[TableName].[ColumnName]` in one of those properties?

Comment: Assuming you mean the bit at the bottom headed "Field Properties" - I've looked at the properties for every field in the table and there's nothing like that. I also clicked Property Sheet in the Table Tools ribbon, but that didn't show anything much, certainly nothing that looked wrong.

Comment: I meant the table's property sheet.  Based on your description, I think you already found it.  Just below the "Property Sheet" heading, it should say "Selection type: Table Properties".

Comment: Argh. Found it. I was looking at the wrong thing. Somehow it's got an Order By in the table's property sheet that references the other table - I can't imagine how!!. Thanks for that. If you put it up as an answer, I'll tick it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the table in *Design View* and then open its property sheet.  Make sure you examine the *table's* property sheet (it should say *"Selection type: Table Properties"* just below the *"Property Sheet"* heading).

Look for `[TableName].[ColumnName]` in one of those properties.

I was thinking of the *Filter* and Order By properties; you confirmed it was in the *Order By*.

That can happen when you apply a sort option from the ribbon and then save that sort with the table's design.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same problem. The parameter mine was asking for what not even one of my field names. I finally figured out that I must have hit the space key in an empty field when I was adding some new fields to the table. I deleted about 10 empty fields to make sure I got all the mistakes and it cleared up my problem. I hope this helps!